# My site doesn't get indexed for some reason

Tags: php, redirect, seo

I use http://www.auditmypc.com/xml-sitemap.asp to check if it gets crawled or not.

`http://www.domain.com/` does NOT get crawled
`http://www.domain.com/bg/` does NOT get crawled
`http://www.domain.com/bg/medical/` does unleash the huge crawling activity

also, it matters for some reason whether `/bg/medical/` has `www`. If it doesn't, crawling doesn't work again.

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ site/lib/router.php
```

router.php file relevant parts:

```
@list($uri,$queryString) = explode('?',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],2);
$uri = trim($uri,'/');

$_GET = array();
parse_str($queryString,$_GET);

if (empty($uri)) {
header('Location: /bg/home');
die();
}
@list($first,$second,$third,$fourth) = explode('/', $uri, 4);

///////////// VARIETY OF SWITCHES HERE with stuff like that:
        if(empty($second))
        switch($first){
            case 'bg':
                redirect('/'.$first.'/home/');

            case 'en':
                redirect('/'.$first.'/home/');
        }
```

I think it's somewhere in the redirects that things get lost. But I can't figure out why. 
Any help would be appreciated.

robots.txt:

```
User-agent: * 
Allow: /
```

and the definition of `redirect` function:

```
function redirect($url) {
header("Location: $url");
die();
}
```

EDIT: if that helps also:

```
Header fields

HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Date
Thu, 13 Jan 2011 11:02:13 GMT
Content-Length
0
Location
/bg/home
Keep-Alive
timeout=5, max=100
Connection
Keep-Alive
Content-Type
text/html
Server
Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips- rhel5 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
X-Powered-By
PHP/5.2.11
```

Comment: giving us the real url would help to track what happens...

Comment: replace domain with ortho_shop as one word without the underscore and its bg instead of com. The reason i hide it is that stackoverflow gets indexed super well, and i dont want this article results to appear in the search before the actual site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your site showing up in a google search (including the homepage), so it must have been crawled by google. I don't know this auditmypc tool, but i think it's more likely the problem is in this tool.

Try google webmaster tools instead: http://www.google.com/webmasters/

There you can really see if google indexed your site.

Comment: I have it in webmaster tools, but that doesn't help me much. it says the crawl access is good, and that it has crawled on the site, but doesn't really say what it actually read. and has a few minor problems, that are out of scope.

Comment: To find out what google has indexed, just "search" on site:domain.com. That's probably what Niek did. That will show you all the pages google knows about.

Comment: The problem is that the site is indexed, everything is there, but it won't show up at all when searching without the name of the domain/company. And to be honest, our country in our language, there aren't that many good sites on the topic, so it should normally pop up among the first ones. Instead it doesn't appear by keywords at all

Comment: There is probably no technical problem that's causing this. Just bad SEO. For example, you have no text at all on your homepage, and the links on your homepage have generic texts like "products". I suggest you read something about SEO and adjust your site accordingly.